# What is the molar extinction coefficient of azorubine (carmoisine, E 122)

Tags: reference-request, spectrophotometry, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I'd be grateful for the molar extinction coefficient ε of azorubine at the absorption maximum (about 520 nm), with an authoritative reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the following value (see the very comprehensive reference below):

molar absorption coefficient $\pu{\epsilon = 24 000 M-1 cm-1}$ ($\pu{510 nm}$) in water

CARMOISINE (E122), CAS Number 3567-69-9, (3~{E})-4-oxo-3-[(4-sulfonaphthalen-1-yl)hydrazinylidene]naphthalene-1-sulfonic acid, SMILES(canonical): C1=CC=C2C(=C1)C(=CC=C2S(=O)(=O)O)NN=C3C=C(C4=CC=CC=C4C3=O)S(=O)(=O)O,

**References**

Taniguchi, M. and Lindsey, J. S. (2018), Database of Absorption and Fluorescence Spectra of >300 Common Compounds for use in PhotochemCAD. Photochem Photobiol, 94: 290-327. doi:10.1111/php.12860
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/php.12860

Originally from

463. Kamachi, S., K. Wakabayashi, K. Zaitsu and Y. Ohkura (1983)
     New chromogenic substrates for the assy of esterases — acetates
     and butyrates of phenolic naphthylazo compounds with sulfonic
     acid group. Chem. Pharm. Bull. 31, 162–167.
464. Lin, J.-J., D. Liu, C. Fu and T.-Z. Li (2012) Optimization of
     Fenton-like degradation conditions of Acid Red 14 azo dye under
     low frequency ultrasonic irradiation. Asian J. Chem. 24, 4453–
     4457.
465. Arvin, M., G. Dehghan, M. A. Hosseinpourfeizi and A. A. Moosavi-
     Movahedi (2013) Spectroscopic and electrochemical studies on
     the interaction of carmoisine food additive with native calf thymus
     DNA. Spectrosc. Lett. 46, 250–256.